# Query related to production environment

Tags: mongodb, mongrel, mongrel-cluster

I have configured my production environment with the following details:

```
1. Three config server
2. Two routers (`mongos`)
3. Two shards of three node replica sets.
```

My question is: I am trying to connect to the sharded database with the help of the mongo java driver. So, if I give my two `mongos` IPs for connection, how will the driver select one `mongos` for routing data, in other words which `mongos` will be selected as the primary router and how will the other one be picked if one goes down.

Answer (score 0):

When you create your MongoClient in the driver, you simply give it a list of `mongos` to use rather than a single `mongos` - the driver will then automatically fail over if one goes down.  Check the relevant API docs here:

http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.11.3/com/mongodb/MongoClient.html#MongoClient(java.util.List)